# Download Count on ordinary file in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-files

I want to get download count for simple file which i have added in page by 'a href' tag.

File is pdf file.

I have already tried download-count module. but no result.

File is added by a href tag in one of the template.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a database table to store the data (Probably 2 columns are all you'll need `fid` and `download_count`).
2. Make sure that your files is saved as `private files`.
3. Create a custom module and implement [hook_file_download](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7)(), inside this hook implementation write the code to add/update the file download count.